# Aspect ratios for sprites in Unity3d

Tags: unity, sprites, ios, resolution

I'm using Unity3D version 5.0.

I'm wondering what the best way to deal with changing resolutions in Unity is.  In Swift I can just use the @x2/@x3 in order for it to pick the correct sprite for it to use.  Is there a similar mechanism in Unity?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would read [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html) and [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ArtAssetBestPracticeGuide.html) for some helpful tips.

The short answer is no, but Unity has some very convenient and efficient tools to handle scaling images. So ideally you should choose the highest resolution you wish to support, and let the engine scale it from there. I'm not 100% on this, but I think I read somewhere that when you build the project for export, Unity's optimizer will pre-generate scaled images for use in the final product.